# .net core 6 publish profiles to replace appsettings with visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am writing a .NET core 6 console application for which I would like to replace the `appsettings.json` file to `appsettings.envname.json` whenever I publish for `envname`.

The file should be named `appsettings.json` basically based on the publish profile I would like to use a different appsettings.

How can I do that in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In console application you can write into your Program.cs:

```
var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                     .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                     .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                     .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true)
                     .AddEnvironmentVariables();
Configuration = builder.Build();
```